# iPad's update to iOS 8 already taken almost 2 days

Tags: ipad, ios

MY iPad 2 was updating to iOS 8 since 2 days ago and up till now, it's still not finished. I'm not sure if this is normal or not, but the progress bar is at the same spot for a whole day already. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the device into [Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1808) & restore from iTunes.

To force Reset, press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons for at least 10 seconds, until you see the Apple logo.

If you have previously made a backup, you can then restore from that backup, either via [iTunes](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1414) or directly from [iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521)

Comment: I couldn't reset it no matter how long I hold the sleep/wake button. There's no response from the iPad no matter what I hold.

Comment: I added a line on force reset

Comment: You need to hold BOTH buttons for 10 seconds in order to force a reset

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not normal. Restart the installation.

Comment: May I ask how I do that? Does it make me lose some data?

Comment: This Answer doesn't really help in any way. It would be better to include details as to how to achieve that.